# Call parent scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to show a div-tag with ng-show in a directive. 
This is not working. All methods in myFunctions are called, but the boolean value in function1 does not change.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showDiv = false;
}]);
```

the directive:

```
myApp.directive('travelInformation', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            showDiv: '=showDiv',
            myFunction: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            this[scope.myFunction](element);

            this.function1 = function (element) {
                scope.showDiv = true; 
                console.log(scope.showDiv); //still false
            };

            this.function2 = function (element) {
                //do something else
            };
        }
    }
});
```

html:

```
<div travel-information show-div="showDiv" data-my-function="'function1'">
   Function1: here the showDiv should be changed
</div>

<div travel-information show-div="showDiv" data-my-function="'function2'">
    Function2
</div>

<div ng-show="showDiv">
    I am visible
</div>
```

How is it possible???

If I delete the second div-tag with  data-my-function="'function2'"than it works.

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do here with a `this[scope.myFunction](element);` and why you're using `this.function1` instead of `scope.function1`? Perhaps stick an example on plunkr?

Comment: in [scope.myFunctions](element) all the functions are saved which are defined in the html and are implemented in the directive. In this case function1 and function2. They were called automatically when the link has the the element on Focus. So in first round function1 is called  and in the second function2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't work. You are trying to call methods before they are created.

If you move the call of functions after the variable initialization (or create actual functions) it should work

```
this.function1 = function (element) {
    scope.showDiv = true; 
    console.log(scope.showDiv);
};

this.function2 = function (element) {
    //do something else
};

// move this to end
this[scope.myFunction](element);
```

-- or --

```
this.function1 = function1;
this.function2 = function2;
this[scope.myFunction](element);

function function1(element) {
    scope.showDiv = true; 
    console.log(scope.showDiv);
};

function function2(element) {
    //do something else
};
```

Comment: yes ur right. i created a codepen. and its working. But it´s strange. in my project it is not working. http://codepen.io/minas/pen/ZbVYov

Comment: Then you have some other code which is interfering. Are you referencing the correct files? Do you have cache enabled in your browser so that you are using old code perhaps? You can turn of JavaScript cache in developer tools in most browsers

Comment: I have to try it. But thanks for your help and advise

Comment: If I add an intervall in the directive than it does not work. I have in my project an interval, where I call the scope-functions. pls check again: http://codepen.io/minas/pen/ZbVYov

Comment: When you call interval the `this` reference is different inside that function than the this pointer in your controller. You need to safe a reference to `this` outside the interval call. `var that = this; $interval(function() { that.whatever(); }, 2000);`

Comment: the that is not working. Can you please give an full example. Maybe in fiddle. You can copy my code from  codepen.io/minas/pen/ZbVYov

Comment: ok i got it. Thanks. I also have to save the element. than it works!

Answer (score 0):

Isolated Scopes can't access to a $parent scope because they have no parent scopes, they can access only to the **$root**.

Comment: You are passing a value from $parent to directive, this is a sharing not an access to $parent scope. Isolated Scopes are "sandboxed"!

Comment: Both of the scope variables showDiv and myFunction are passed to the directive with double binding. They are therefore bound to eachother and an update in the directive affects the one in the parent scope. The question is not related to parent scopes as it is written.